# Want to set $error variable in laravel so that i will display errors in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

as i can see in my blade like

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
       <span class="invalid-feedback">
         <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
      </span>
@endif
```

i want to set errors so that $error variable will contain error message i know in this case its getting error from default
suppose want to show custom error message to the $error variable how to do that and i have not passed that variable to the blade still it has access can u please tell me short working of that sorry but i am new to laravel

Comment: have you try the Laravel error handler ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors

Comment: You could set custom error messages, by passing the messages as third argument to the Validator. Check out the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages) .The $errors variable is flashed to session and is automatically made available to all views by laravel.

Comment: try changing error message in  resources->lang->en->validation.php->'email' => 'The :attribute must be a valid email address.' to 'email'=>'your custom error message.'

Comment: nice thanks guyz really helped a lot

Comment: @linktoahref thanks

Comment: @parthu_panther Thanks

Comment: @kevinniel Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `withErrors()` method to `redirect` with `error` message and pass your `custom` error message array as `third` parameter in `make()` method.

```
$messages = [
        'email.required' => 'Your custom error message',
    ];
$rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    ];

$validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules,$messages);

if($validator->fails()){
     return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel0414

Comment: @PranavMandlik w/c :)